# Angular 2 - form validation fail

Tags: angular

I got form like this

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
    template: `
        <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
            <textarea (keyup)="valuechange($event)" #input  name="detail" id="detail" formControlName="detail"></textarea>
            <div *ngIf="formGroup.controls['detail'].dirty && formGroup.controls['detail'].invalid">This is required</div>

            <button type="submit">Post</button>
        </form>
    `,
})
export class CreateDiscussionComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    constructor(
    ) {
        this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
            detail: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2) ]),
        });
    }
    onSubmit(): void {
        this.submitted = true;
        console.log(this.formGroup.value)
    }
}
```

It has a single textarea. What it does is if input is not empyty, submit when click submit

Problem: the form will submit even textarea is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the form instance to the onSubmit() and then check if form is valid.

HTML:

```
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formGroup)"
```

TypeScript:

```
onSubmit(form) {
    if(form.invalid){
       return;
    }
    this.submitted = true;
    console.log(this.formGroup.value)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add `disabled` attribute to your element

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!formGroup.valid" >Post</button>
```

Your error message isn't appearing because you had used `formGroup.controls['detail'].dirty && formGroup.controls['detail'].invalid` condition, where you're first verifying form is `dirty` or not `&&` it should be `invalid`. This condition will never satisfied if user directly submit a form without touching any field.

---

Better you can call `onSubmit` method when `formGroup` is valid.

```
(ngSubmit)="formGroup.valid && onSubmit()"
```

Comment: I tried the `disabled` attr, it gives a yellow warning in the console, saying disabled should not be used with reactive form.

Comment: how about showing error message after submit `empty value`?